# SQL Like or REGEXP filter results even when everything should be matched

Tags: mysql, sql-like

this is what i have

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.type AS node_type, product.* 
FROM ml_node node 
LEFT JOIN ml_content_type_product product 
  ON node.vid = product.vid 
WHERE (node.type in('product')) 
  AND product.field_sockel_value REGEXP '.*' 
  AND product.field_artikel_value REGEXP '.*' 
  AND product.field_leistung_value REGEXP '.*'
  AND product.field_licht_farbe_value REGEXP '.*' 
  AND product.field_rubrik_value REGEXP '.*' 
  AND product.field_artikelgruppe_value REGEXP '.*' 
ORDER BY product.field_artikel_value
```

Having these where-conditions I would assume that this gives the same results as:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.type AS node_type, product.* 
FROM ml_node node 
LEFT JOIN ml_content_type_product product 
  ON node.vid = product.vid 
WHERE (node.type in('product')) 
ORDER BY product.field_artikel_value
```

But it does not. The first returns 494 rows and the last one gives 717. So there's missing a bunch of rows. When I use this query

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.type AS node_type, product.* 
FROM ml_node node 
LEFT JOIN ml_content_type_product product 
  ON node.vid = product.vid 
WHERE (node.type in('product')) 
  AND product.field_artikel_value REGEXP '.*' 
  AND product.field_leistung_value REGEXP '.*'
  AND product.field_rubrik_value REGEXP '.*' 
  AND product.field_artikelgruppe_value REGEXP '.*' 
ORDER BY product.field_artikel_value
```

I also do get 717 rows. So… what could it be that makes those removed conditions so special? The columns are all of type longtext (because the cms does so) and have the exact same attributes.

**BTW** i noticed the same behavior when using LIKE instead of REGEXP.

Comment: I've added some extra information to my answer to hopefully give you what you're after - based on your comment under Ocaso's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `LEFT JOIN` you also get lines where `product.field_sockel_value` or `product.field_licht_farbe_value` is `NULL`. These line got filtered in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: How do i get those rows as well?

Comment: Just add a `OR product.field_sockel_value IS NULL` and so on for every column: `AND (product.field_sockel_value REGEXP '.*' OR product.field_sockel_value IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by NULL values in certain rows.  A NULL field will evaluate to False when compared with another value.

If you want to get all the values back with your second query, move the product-table-related expressions in the `WHERE` clause into your join criteria, so you end up with:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.type AS node_type, product.* 
FROM ml_node node 
  LEFT JOIN ml_content_type_product product 
  ON node.vid = product.vid 
    AND product.field_sockel_value REGEXP '.*' 
    AND product.field_artikel_value REGEXP '.*' 
    AND product.field_leistung_value REGEXP '.*'
    AND product.field_licht_farbe_value REGEXP '.*' 
    AND product.field_rubrik_value REGEXP '.*' 
    AND product.field_artikelgruppe_value REGEXP '.*' 
WHERE (node.type in('product')) 
ORDER BY product.field_artikel_value
```

This will ensure the join is only made when it meets your other criteria, but will still return all of your `node` records, where the `type` is correct.